# JBoss AS7 JMS cluster with Spring app

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, cluster-computing, hornetq, spring-jms

I have a problem with Spring webapp running on JBoss 7 JMS Cluster.

I set up JMS cluster by this [article](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/24/clustering-of-the-messaging-subsystem-hornetq-in-jboss-as7-and-eap-6/) - cluster is using shared journal. I'm using live1 and backup1 configuration from the [example](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/24/clustering-of-the-messaging-subsystem-hornetq-in-jboss-as7-and-eap-6/). For the example switching between live and backup server with app which contains Message Driven Bean is working.

I created simple Spring web app which register JMS listener.

My jms-config.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="ConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="testQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jms/queue/test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="listener" class="eu.cuptech.jms.ExampleListener" />

    <bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="ConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="testQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

ExampleListener.java looks like this:

```
package eu.cuptech.jms;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            System.out.println("MESSAGE TEXT: " + msg);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

When I start the live server, messages are handled by ExampleListener - it is OK. When I start backup server I got error **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException** beacause of `ConnectionFactory` is not exposed under JNDI for backup server - then only main server is working it is not a cluster. When live server fails now no backup is here.

When I try set `lazy-init="true"` and `loadOnStartup="false"` (+ proxy interface) for ConnectionFactory and testQueue nothing change because listenerContainer will create it when backup server is started. I need listenerContainer will wait until backup server become live and then will connect to the Queue.

I tried `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` also, but with the same result - resource under JNDI name is not available on backup server.

Here is a [webapp source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57072459/jms-spring-test-web.zip) build it using maven `mvn package` (Eclipse project).
Here is a simple JMS [client source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57072459/jms-test-client.zip) (Eclipse project).

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the backup server is a passive HornetQ Messaging Server and can not have any producers or consumers before failover.

HornetQ Docs (Live - Backup Groups): http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/#d0e11266

Comment: It doesn't have any before failover because an app never start on the server. Even after live server fails, then backup should become live.